# Excel module - VBA: Function to count colored cells, if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

people!

I do not often refer to VBA in Excel, but when I do, I find answer by Googling.
However, there is no answer for my current need.

I have following function to count colours in range (possible source - http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sum-count-cells-by-color.htm):

```
    Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult

    lCol = rColor.Interior.Color


    If SUM = True Then
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then
                vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell)
            End If
        Next rCell
    Else
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then
                vResult = 1 + vResult
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If

    ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

I have tried to extend it to count colours in specific range, if condition is met, but failed.

I ask you, dear colleagues, to help me to extend the function to fulfill the need:

**count number of colours in specific range, if word "foo" is met in another range**.

Comment: Why not do `For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.Color = lCol And rCell.Value = "foo" Then
                vResult = 1 + vResult`

Comment: Also, this code is clearly taken from here [http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sum-count-cells-by-color.htm](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sum-count-cells-by-color.htm), with the credit removed. If you're going to present someone else's code at least credit them!

Comment: Josh Friedlander, unfortunately, even such hard coded solution does not work. I need something like "COUNTIF" function, so I could enter desired second range and word into parenthesis.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(vResult, rCell.Value2)` ?

Comment: Jeeped, why should it be?

Answer (score 2):

According to your post, you want to `Count` the number of coloured cells, so I made the modifiactions below to your `Function` to work as you posted.

`StrCond` is the third parameter, which is `Optional` to check also for a certain `String` in the `rCell.Value`.

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional StrCond As String) As Long

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult As Long

    lCol = rColor.Interior.color

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.color = lCol Then
            If StrCond <> "" Then
                If rCell.Value = StrCond Then
                    vResult = vResult + 1
                End If
            Else
                vResult = vResult + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

    ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

*Screen-shot* of cell's value after testing this `Function`:

[image]

*Screen-shot* of cell's value after testing this `Function` without the 3rd parameter (getting `5` as expected):

[image]

Comment: This is really awesome solution, if you define desired word in parenthesis. However, I do not get it: why the function does not work on sheet1, but works on sheet2 with similar example as yours?..

Comment: @Algo this is not what you wanted ?

Comment: No, no, Shai Rado! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! I just trying to figure out, why it does not work on my active sheet X)

Comment: @Algo you have this code in a reguler Module, right ?

Comment: @Algo are you sure all the parameters are set the same ? try a new example in a new created sheet

Comment: I understood, why your function does not work with my test data. We need to edit the code once again X) The thing is that colored cell is looked for in one range, but a word - in other range. The word is not in colored cell(s). What does "If StrCond <> "" Then" mean? Is it "less or greater than empty"?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Shai Rado**'s solution I could modify the script so that it takes two ranges: 1st for desired colored cell, 2nd for desired word. The script is:

```
    Function ConditionalColorFunction(rColor As Range, rColoredRange As Range, StrCond As String, rCondRange As Range) As Long

    Dim rColoredCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iCondRangeColumnsAmount As Integer
    Dim vResult

    lCol = rColor.Interior.Color
    iCondRangeColumnsAmount = rCondRange.Columns.Count

    For Each rColoredCell In rColoredRange
        If rColoredCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then
           For i = 1 To iCondRangeColumnsAmount
               If Cells(rColoredCell.Row, i).Value = StrCond Then
                   vResult = 1 + vResult
                   Exit For
               End If
           Next
        End If
    Next rColoredCell

    ConditionalColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

**rColor** - cell with desired color.

**rColoredRange** - range with cells with different colours.

**StrCond** - desired word.

**rCondRange** - range with cells with different words.

Comment: not cool what you did, taking 95% of my code, then posting your own answer and accepting.

Comment: @Shai Rado, it was accepted as the correct solution to the task. But all fame in helping is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range) As Long

    Dim rCell       As Range
    Dim lCol        As Long
    Dim bFooMet     As Boolean
    Dim lResult     As Long

    lCol = rColor.Interior.Color

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then lResult = lResult + 1
        If rCell.value = "foo" Then bFooMet = True
    Next rCell

    If bFooMet Then
        ColorFunction = lResult
    Else
        ColorFunction = -1
    End If

End Function
```

If you activesheet looks like this:

[image]

and you write in the immediate window`?ColorFunction(cells(1,1),selection)` in the immediate window you would get `11` as a result - the number of cells in yellow, with the same background as `A1`.

If you do not have `foo` in the selected range, you would get `-1`.

If you want to count only the `yellow` cells with `foo` inside, it could be like this:

```
Option Explicit

Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range) As Long

    Dim rCell       As Range
    Dim lCol        As Long
    Dim bFooMet     As Boolean
    Dim lResult     As Long

    lCol = rColor.Interior.Color

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.value = "foo" And rCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then
            lResult = lResult + 1
        End If
    Next rCell

    ColorFunction = lResult

End Function
```

Comment: your hard coded solution works fine. Thank you! I will bear in mind such option too.